# How to get private constant

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to retrieve a private constant from an external contract using assembly? Since constants are typically stored in bytecode rather than in storage, I'm curious whether it's feasible to access a private constant at the contract level.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the EXTCODECOPY opcode to copy the constant (assuming it's actually used in the target contract). Although this solution doesn't scale beyond 1 particular contract, as you would need to hard-code the size and location of the constant.